# Samsung Smart Tv Return Button

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I created the app for the samsung smart tv. I tested my app using the Remote test system. All the functionalities are working properly except the return key. When i press the return button  it is returning to the home screen but i want my app to return to the previous screen of my app. This is working correctly while i test this in the emulator.

I checked this by giving alers in the return key functionality. It is alerting that after it is returning to the homw screen.

Can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 4):

RETURN and EXIT key are followed by default behavior to closing application and going back to smart hub or tv broadcast screen.

You should implement prevent default behavior, please look at this page: http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00009/sfkey_preventdefault.html

Answer (score 4):

In Samsung Smart TV, RETURN default action is return to Home, as you can see in SDK documentation:

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/

You must to include this line in your code:

```
sf.key.preventDefault();
```

Before your code to customize RETURN button action.

For example (case from a Switch):

```
case tvKey.RETURN :
     sf.key.preventDefault();
     window.history.go(-1);
     break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem for a basic Javascript project. I resolved it by adding `event.preventDefault();`, for example:

```
Main.keyDown = function()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    case tvKey.KEY_RETURN:      
    case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_RETURN: event.preventDefault();
}
```

For Apps Framework you can use this function:

```
sf.key.preventDefault();
```

Comment: if i want to return to smart hub screen when smart hub button is clicked how i can archive that ?